# Can't make WPF Usercontrol update in designer

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm really losing my mind , I did everything I found on net and still no chance.

I have a simple rectangle and a red/blue enum. I want to animate its color in designer by changing value by a user.

**MyCustomUC.xaml.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace WpfApp1
{
    public enum Pill
    { red = 1, blue = 2 }

    public partial class MyCustomUC : UserControl
    {
        private Color ColorToAnim = Color.FromRgb(255, 0, 0);

        public static DependencyProperty pill_mode = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "pillmodeval", typeof(Pill), typeof(MyCustomUC),
         new PropertyMetadata(Pill.blue, // ISSUE 1 : Default Value Is Not Working , It's always 0
         new PropertyChangedCallback(OnValueChanged)
        )); 

        [Category("Pills")]
        public Pill pillmodeval
        {
            get { return (Pill)GetValue(pill_mode); }
            set { SetValue(pill_mode, value); }
        }

        public MyCustomUC()
        {
            InitializeComponent(); //// Not Firing Either 
            color_output.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(ColorToAnim);

            // ISSUE 2 : MessageBox.Show , Debug.WriteLine Not Work On Design Mode
            MessageBox.Show("MyCustomUC Created!");
            Debug.WriteLine("MyCustomUC Created!");
        }

        void AnimateColor()
        {
            ColorAnimation new_color_anim = new ColorAnimation(ColorToAnim, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
            color_output.Fill.BeginAnimation(SolidColorBrush.ColorProperty, new_color_anim);
        }

        void UpdateColor()
        {
            if (pillmodeval == Pill.red)
            {
                ColorToAnim = Color.FromRgb(0, 0, 255);
                pillmodeval = Pill.blue;
            }
            else
            {
                ColorToAnim = Color.FromRgb(255, 0, 0);
                pillmodeval = Pill.red;
            }
        }

        private void color_output_MouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            UpdateColor();
        }

        private static void OnValueChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            MyCustomUC custom_uc = (MyCustomUC)d;
            // ISSUE 3 : AnimateColor not working in Designer
            custom_uc.AnimateColor();
        }

        private void UserControl_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            // ISSUE 2 : MessageBox.Show , Debug.WriteLine Not Work On Design Mode
            MessageBox.Show("MyCustomUC Loaded!");
            Debug.WriteLine("MyCustomUC Loaded!");
        }
    }
}
```

**MyCustomUC.xaml :**

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApp1.MyCustomUC"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="100" d:DesignWidth="100" Loaded="UserControl_Loaded">
    <Grid>
            <Rectangle x:Name="color_output" Fill="Black" MouseUp="color_output_MouseUp" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

**Issues :**

- Constructor calls not work in Designer
- OnLoad calls not work in Designer
- AnimateColor not works in Designer
- DependencyProperty default value is always zero , not works with enum.

How can I make this code work ?

Comment: Visual Studios XAML Designer is a static representation of the actual markup. It doesn't execute any methods. It uses property default values for display. But you can provide a [design time data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-previewer/design-time-datahttps://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-previewer/design-time-data) context to get a more complete look of the current view.

Comment: To design and [preview animations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/xaml-tools/animate-objects-in-xaml-designer?view=vs-2019) or visual states you can use [Blend for Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/xaml-tools/creating-a-ui-by-using-blend-for-visual-studio?view=vs-2019). It offers a lot extras to generate view code, without writing much code, like triggers, behaviors, eventhandlers, animations, visual states, templates, etc

Comment: @BionicCode But I see it's possible , everything in http://materialdesigninxaml.net/ library happens in real-time in designer.

Comment: @BionicCode So you mean it's only possible in markup code not viewmodel right ? and what about defaul enum ?

Comment: What do you mean by _"happens in real time"_? You can click buttons and trigger animations? I doubt it. It has nothing to do with the library. This is how the designer works. But you can display animations that are not triggered by an interaction like `ProgressBar` in indeterminate mode. You can set custom values to initialize bindings to a view model e.g. `TextBlock.Text` or `ListView.ItemsSource` to show some design time values. Check [Sample Data in the WPF and Silverlight Designer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/wpfsldesigner/sample-data-in-the-wpf-and-silverlight-designer)

Comment: What d you mean with default enum?

Comment: @BionicCode I mentioned in my question , my enum doesn't work as default value , it's always 0 instead of 1 or 2 , I tried numbers but no chance, By real-time i mean , there's some controllers with switch like true , false when you change the Boolean property it changes in designer with animation.

Answer (score 0):

That's how Visual Studio XAML designer works. You can't see your animations because you reference your library as Solution Project. VS designer wouldn't run any complie-time code at design time for libraries which are referenced as Solution Project.

[image: User control referenced as Project]

VS designer will show you only changes that could be applied without compiling the whole library. For that instead of using behind code you have to use XAML bindings, eg:

```xml
<UserControl 
    x:Class="MyUserControlLibrary.UserControl1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyUserControlLibrary"
    mc:Ignorable="d" >
    
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BooleanToVisibilityConverter" />
    </UserControl.Resources>

    <StackPanel  DataContext="{Binding Mode=Default, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}">
        <TextBlock  Visibility="{Binding ShowIt, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}">Abc</TextBlock>
    </StackPanel>
    
</UserControl>
```

```cs
public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
{
    public UserControl1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public bool ShowIt
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(ShowItProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ShowItProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ShowItProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("ShowIt", typeof(bool), typeof(UserControl1), new PropertyMetadata(true));

}
```

---

You can see animations in controls from materialdesigninxaml.net library because you reference it directly as DLL library. If you reference your library as compiled DLL then animation should work as expected.

[image: User control referenced as DLL]